# Can't insert rows into SQL Server table that contains triggers ( F Sharp SQL Provider )

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am using the Sqlprovider driver and hitting an issue on creating new records - that appears to make the driver useless.

```
        let foundProductMaybe = query {
            for p in ctx.Dbo.Products do
            where (p.DefaultSupplierSku.Value = pl.supplierSku)
            select (Some p)
            exactlyOneOrDefault
        }
        match foundProductMaybe with
            | Some foundProduct ->
                updateProduct(foundProduct,pl,ctx)
            | None -> addProduct(pl, ctx)
        product.Id <- Guid.NewGuid()
        product.Code <- "some code"
        .... etc 
        ctx.SubmitUpdates()
```

I get the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The target table 'dbo.Products' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: This is apparently a [known issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/322). There's a suggested workaround, but it looks like it requires you to build your own version of SQLProvider: "create a fork and remove line 302-307 of Providers.MsSqlServer.fs"

Comment: @brianberns  thanks.  I actually ended up using SQLclient.. which is the one you use I think from memory.   It's actually nicer to use than I expected with all the embedded SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue related to SQL Server, not necessarily SQLServerProvider, it seems to me. Here's an article that discusses the mechanism of this behaviour. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/update-with-output-clause-8211-triggers-8211-and-sqlmoreresults/ba-p/383457

The code that generates the OUTPUT statemens in the SqlProvider appears to be here: https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/blob/8afaad203efe2b3b900a2ad1a6d8a35d66ebe40a/src/SQLProvider.Runtime/Providers.MsSqlServer.fs#L370
The OUTPUT clause is generated only if the table has primary key.

Perhaps you can change the table and replace the primary key with UNIQUE constraint, which is pretty close in the functionality to the PK constraint and should not affect you in your case.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15

The Unique constraints (and primary keys) are implemented as indexes on the table. Since you use a nonsequential GUID, you might consider ensuring that these indexes are created as NONCLUSTERED.